# Set minDate to Today in Bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using Bootstrap DateTime Picker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I've found the basic option to set a minDate; but, I can't get it to set to today to save my life.  I've tried things like Date(); but, nothing working.  Anyone have any ideas?

Example

```
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
            },
        startDate: new Date()
    });
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you're using the latest version, the `minDate` option is what you'll need to set. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0j1dy3Lg/) with a working example. Hope this helps.

```
$('#date').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    icons: {
      time: "fa fa-clock-o",
      date: "fa fa-calendar",
      up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
      down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
    },
    minDate: moment()
});
```

Comment: this will only work if you include the additional moment.js library

Answer (score 11):

```
$(".datepicker-custom-flight").datepicker({
    startDate: "dateToday"
})
```

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation / reference to documentation.

Comment: @mickmackusa I was wondering the same thing. startDate seems to be documented there: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate . Regarding the format, it seems just putting startDate: "today" or startDate: "yesterday" both work. I'm looking for what is doing the parsing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code, by avoiding additional scripts.

Example

```
var todayDate = new Date().getDate();
var endD= new Date(new Date().setDate(todayDate - 15));
var currDate = new Date();
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                       
    autoclose: true,
    startDate : endD,
    endDate : currDate
});
```

Comment: by simply using startDate instead of minDate it works!