# Working with Eonasdan datetime picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have implemented datetimepicker as follows:

```
$('#txtStartDate').datetimepicker({ useCurrent: false, locale: _defaultCulture[0], format: 'L' });
$('#txtEndDate').datetimepicker({ useCurrent: false, locale: _defaultCulture[0], format: 'L' });
```

Can anyone tell how can I disable date before to current/today's date?

I read the documentation on http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate, but not able to implement as it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set minDate to Today in Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095415/set-mindate-to-today-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your **JS**

Include *moment.js* in your external js.(*moment.js* is must to use Eonasdan datetime picker).

As mentioned by @VincenzoC  For more details follow the [**link**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

```
$(function() {
  $('#YourID').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    useCurrent: false,
    minDate: moment()
  });

});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/92j8cz7r/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Please note that momentjs is [**required**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) for eonasdan-datetimepicker, so you **have to** import it to make the component work.

Comment: @Raviteja Thanks for the help ! That really helped !